# Find textbox in fragment from parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, textbox

I want to change the text in a fragment from the code I the parent activity. I have tried referencing the fragment to no success. I'm not using this properly?

How can I do this?

Code in parent activity:

```
 Fragment frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_extra);
 txtCurrent = (TextView) frg.getView().findViewById(R.id.txtCountries);
```

But it returns a null reference.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the frag null?

Comment: @Kristy Welsh yes

Comment: if the frag is null, have you added the frag with the support manager?

Comment: @KristyWelsh Sorry for not replying. No, they use the bottom navigation bar to load. I think